# Is it possible to limit the number of visible posts per follower per day on Twitter?

Tags: twitter

While using Twitter (web version) everyone wants to get as much important information as possible. Sometimes some followers are posting many posts per day, but you would like to see also others posts. E.g. daily I want to see at most one post per follower, so that no one can spam my board.

Is possible to limit the number of posts per follower shown to me in a day?

Answer (score 2):

No, as of now there is no official way to do so.

There is a [**mute**](https://support.twitter.com/articles/20171399) option, you can mute anyone and they didn't get notify about it. But once you mute someone, their any of tweets will not show on your timline.

Other option is just unfollow that person and put him/her in a [**list**](https://support.twitter.com/articles/76460), so whenever you want see their tweets, just view the list, all their tweet will be there. Unfollowing anyone will not notify them.